# Error On Parsing JSONData

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have this Json Array

```
[{"Fname":"Axe","Lname":"Venture" },{"Fname":"dsa","Lname":"das"}]
```

I am Using JSON.net to deserialize the Json array. My Class is as below

```
public class Cifo
    {
        public string Fname { get; set; }
        public string Lname { get; set; }
    }
```

The json array will be store in a string namely JSONData , when there is only 1 Json Data such as {"Fname":"Axe","Lname":"Venture" } . my code will not return any error . but when I have more than 1 JSON array data like above . I will get an exception "Cannot deserialize JSON array into type 'myClassName+Cifo'."

I am using this code to deserialize `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Cifo>(JSONData)`

How can I parse all the json data and store into an object ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to deserializa to a list

```
 var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Cifo>>(JSONData)
```